# Codename one: how to use existing gif as loading animation when calling web service

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

I have a gif created by some designer which we want to show when consuming a web service as a "loading" animation, but i can't find how to do it, i found InfinitProgress which you can personalize using an image and the animation rotates it, but in this case the animation we need is not rotation but shape change, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following commented code, maybe it does what you asked:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());

// Replace the "loadingIcon" with the animated gif that you want
Label loadingIcon = new Label(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, "Label", 5));
loadingIcon.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);

Dialog loadingAnimation = new Dialog();
loadingAnimation.setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE));
Style dlgStyle = loadingAnimation.getDialogStyle();
dlgStyle.setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
dlgStyle.setBgTransparency(0);
loadingAnimation.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, loadingIcon);

Button doTask = new Button("Tap here to do a task");
doTask.addActionListener(l -> {
    loadingAnimation.showModeless();
    Log.p("Some tasks simulated by a sleep of five seconds");
    // Remove the UITimer and add your network tasks
    // Call loadingAnimation.dispose() when the tasks are ended
    new UITimer(() -> {
        loadingAnimation.dispose();
    }).schedule(5000, false, loadingAnimation);
});

hi.add(doTask);
hi.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

To use Animated Gifs in your Codename One Project you need this library: https://github.com/codenameone/AnimatedGifSupport/

See also this post about that library:
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/animated-gif-support.html

Don't download manually the library, open the "Codename One" settings of your project, click on Extensions and the click on "Download" of "Animated Gif Support". See this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Yes. There is also another way of clicking `Add Animation` in the designer tool which will create a special animated image from the source gif

Comment: Thanks, i installed and tested AnimatedGifSuport and manually added it to a form to test it, worked fine, final goal is to show it while a web service is sconsumed, any tips or recommendations for this?